# Push command not working says permission denied

Tags: micromax, micromax-funbook

I rooted my micromax p275 and wanted to change its font by replacing /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf with my desired font but i accidentally replaced it with Robot.Regular.ttf.  Now it doesn't starts. 
  I want to push another font file in /system/fonts with the correct name (Roboto-Regular.ttf)  but it doesn't works saying permission denied. I have tried su command  but it just reprints the same commands i type and press enter and thus doing nothing. Any way out friends. I would be greatly helped by you. Every single hint is wanted.

Comment: When you say you want to push another font file, are you referring through `adb push`? That too from recovery??

Comment: Yes,  but is there any other way.  See I just want a Roboto-Regular.ttf in /system/fonts,  whatever might be the way

Comment: You can just a recovery flashable zip modified to include your neccessary file. And then flash it through recovery. Your post doesn't mention anything about your device having  a custom recovery, Do you have custom recovery installed?

Comment: No, i don't have it installed.

Comment: Please describe a little about custom recoveries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup font file and adb is working, then you can just do `adb remount` and try pushing the backup font again. This command is just a shortcut for `adb shell mount -o remount.rw /system`, which remounts `/system` as writable.

If `adb remount` doesn't work, then run `adb root` and try again. (i.e., run `adb root`, `adb remount`, and `adb push /path/to/backup/Roboto-Regular.ttf /system/fonts/`, in that order). I'm not sure how picky adb is about telling it to use root.

Comment: `adb root` wouldn't work on a production kernel which means `adb remount` or `adb shell mount -o remount.rw /system` (sic) would always fail. See [Is there a way for me to run Adb shell as root without typing in 'su'?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/5888)