# Can't modify build.prop

Tags: root-access, build.prop

I have a nexus 6 with version 6.0.1 of android flashed and rooted using Nexus Root toolkit 2.1.4.

I am trying to modify build.prop and doing adb pull/push and even trying to move it to /data/local/tmp and then mv command won't work.

Mounting /system/ rw results in a boot loop and I have to reflash.

I am unsure on how to enable modification of this file.  How can I turn off this "production build" protection on android?

```
adb shell
shell@shamu:/ $ su
root@shamu:/ # mv /data/local/tmp/build.prop /system/ 
mv: /system//build.prop: Read-only file system
1|root@shamu:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
127|root@shamu:/ # mv /data/local/tmp/build.prop /system/
mv: xwrite: No space left on device
1|root@shamu:/ # exit
1|shell@shamu:/ $ exit

adb push build.prop /system/build.prop
failed to copy 'build.prop' to '/system/build.prop': Permission denied

adb shell
shell@shamu:/ $ su
root@shamu:/ # mv /data/build.prop /sy                                         
sys/    system/ 
root@shamu:/ # mv /data/build.prop /system/build.prop                          
mv: /system/build.prop: Read-only file system
```

I'm trying to add this config option to build.prop

```
net.tethering.noprovisioning=true
```

The device has plenty of space as it was just freshly rooted and flashed with a brand new stock image.

Comment: First, tell us exactly what you're trying to change in build.prop. You don't have to take so much turns just to edit that file. Simply use Kernel Adiutor, ES File Explorer or a Buildprop Editor type app. They can do the job smoothly. Second, your mount command actually returned an error code 127. Search it. Third, how much space is left in the device? By my estimate, less than 15MB out of 2GB. And, try with SELinux in permissive mode. It wouldn't hurt. Fourth, why would adb push not fail? See http://android.stackexchange.com/a/5888/96277. Too many issues here. :)

Comment: I just tried BuildProp Editor and it fails to save.  I have SuperSu installed and working and grant the application root privileges.